# JSON values to Map<String,String>

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, json

I am working with a JSON format like the below:

```
{
    "result": {
        "code": 200,
        "info": "OK"
    },
    "data": [{
                "size": "18",
                "categories": [{
                            "code": "es_food",
                            "description": "Food",
                            "subcategories": [{
                                    "code": "es_foodsme",
                                    "description": "Food: small shops"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_supermarket",
                                    "description": "Supermarkets"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "es_sportsandtoys",
                            "description": "Sports and toys",
                            "subcategories": [{
                                    "code": "es_sportbig",
                                    "description": "Sport: chains"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_sport",
                                    "description": "Sportive activities"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_sportandtoys",
                                    "description": "Toys and sport articles"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_toys",
                                    "description": "Toys: chains"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "es_tech",
                            "description": "Technology",
                            "subcategories": [{
                                    "code": "es_techsme",
                                    "description": "Computers and appliances: small shops"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_musicalinstrument",
                                    "description": "Musical instruments"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_techbig",
                                    "description": "Computers and appliances: chains"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_photo",
                                    "description": "Photography"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_telephony",
                                    "description": "Telephony: handset sales"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "es_fashion",
                            "description": "Fashion",
                            "subcategories": [{
                                    "code": "es_fashionbig",
                                    "description": "Fashion: chains"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_fashionsme",
                                    "description": "Fashion: small shops"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_shoe",
                                    "description": "Shoes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_leather",
                                    "description": "Leather goods stores"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "es_jewelry",
                                    "description": "Jewelry and watches"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "es_hotelservices",
                            "description": "Accomodation",
                            "subcategories": [{
                                "code": "es_hotel",
                                "description": "Accommodation"
                            }]
                        },
                        ...
```

I need to show in a selectOption field the description in order to be selected and pass the code associated as parameter in a rest api integration.

I am able to show the description but I am not able to get the code assigned:

This is my controller code:

```
if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
        categories = new list<String>();
        categoriesMap = new Map<String,String>();
        System.debug('parser : ' + parser);
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'description')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        category = parser.getText();
        System.debug('categories : ' + category );
        categories.add(category);
        }
        else if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'code')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        categoryCode = parser.getText();
        System.debug('categoryCode : ' + categoryCode );
        }
        system.debug('Categoria + codigo: ' + category + ' + ' + categoryCode);
        categoriesMap.put(category,categoryCode);
        }

        system.debug('Lista de categorias: ' + categories);

        system.debug('Mapa categoría: ' + categoriesMap);
        catSelectOption = new list<SelectOption>();
        for(String category: categories){
            catSelectOption.add(new SelectOption (category, category));
        }
```

And Visualforce code:

```
<apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" id="merchantsCategory" >
      <apex:selectOption itemvalue="0" itemLabel="All"/>
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!catSelectOption}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

I have tried creating the JSONtoAPex code, but also I have not reached the functionality desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with your current code, when you parse each token you either get the "code" or the "description" and your map will never have both together...

couple of modifications to your code

1. read / parse "code" & "description" and build the map in each run..
2. use the map key & value to build your select option list or directly populate the select option list

below is a rough pseudo code:

```
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {    
    //Check if the token is "code" 
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'code')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        categoryCode = parser.getText(); // value of the code

        //Get the next token & Check if the token is "description" 
        parser.nextToken();
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'description')) {
            parser.nextToken();
            categoryDescription = parser.getText(); // value of the description
        }

        //build the selectoption with the code & description
        catSelectOption.add(new SelectOption (categoryCode, categoryDescription));

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thnks for your reply, I have tried that but I get an error: System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null 
Class.BBVAPageController.getMerchantsCategory: line 125, column 1
Class.BBVAPageController.<init>: line 30, column 1. That line belongs to: catSelectOption.add(new SelectOption (category, categoryCode));